# Reverter uma string e possibilidade de adição de método em objetos nativos no Python

Tags: python, string, classes

No Python, temos o método `reverse`dentro do `List`. Ele reverte a ordem de uma `list`.

Exemplo:

```
[1, 2, 3].reverse() // [3, 2, 1]
```

Porém esse método não está presente numa string.

exemplo (Python):

```
myString = "The String"
myString.reverse() // AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'reverse'
```

1 - Como eu faria para reverter essa string acima no `Python`?

Outra questão é que, no **javascript**, por exemplo, temos o `Prototype`, onde é possível adicionar um método a uma classe nativa da linguagem.

Exemplo (Javascript):

```
  String.prototype.hello = function() {
        return this.toString() +  " hello!";
    } 

    "teste".hello() // "teste hello!"
```

2 - Tem uma maneira de criar um método diretamente na classe String do `Python`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O `reverse` de listas em Python reverte a lista *in place*, alterando os valores da lista ao invés de criar uma lista nova escrita ao avesso. Como strings em Python são imutáveis, não faz muito sentido que elas suprtem o método reverse.

Uma maneira concisa de reverter uma string em Python é usando notação de *slices*

```
>>> 'hello world'[::-1]
'dlrow olleh'
```

Um slice como "abcdefghijklm"[1:9:2] pega os elementos da posição 1 até a 9, de 2 em 2. O slice `[::-1]`, pega os elementos do início ao fim, andando de trás pra frente.

Quanto à segunda pergunta, não recomendo tentar adicionar métodos a classes do sistema já que isso pode resultar em várias coisas indesejáveis. Por exemplo, se dois módulos diferentes do seu sistema resolverem adicionar um método com o mesmo nome a  uma classe do sistema um módulo vai sobrescrever o trabalho do outro. Prefiro definir minhas funções auxiliares como funções normais em um módulo próprio ao invés de como métodos.

Comment: Então, eu também posso usar esse **slices** para fazer substring?

Comment: Sim! Por exemplo, tente `"blah"[1:3]` e `"blah"[2:]`. Funciona com listas e várias outras coisas também.

Comment: Além de não ser recomendado, como você bem diz,, a resposta para a segunda pergunrta é: "não, não é possível". É possível alterar classes da biblioteca padrão do Python, mas só nos casos em que elas sejam escritas em Python puro. Os tipos nativos como strings são escritos em C.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode inverter a string convertendo ela para list, por exemplo:

```
str = "The String"
list = str.split() # list é ['The', 'String']
list.reverse() # list agora é ['String', 'The']
```

Ou, se você quer inverter os caracteres, você faz:

```
str = "The String"
str = str[::-1] # agora str é 'gnirtS ehT'
```